# How to store multiple strings for same category in SQlite database?

Tags: sqlite

I need to assign multiple tags to unique ID's. The final goal is to search for ID's with certain tags.

How should I store the tags? 
That isn't a big database and a simple solution would be best.

```
ID                               | Tags
-----------------------------------------------
b6e490a44fcd5cc92f3d0f97a23f1c83 | foo bar bla
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e | ble blu bla
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you might be able to retain your current table design and use full text search to look for individual tags in the `Tags` column.  But this could lead to problems if search terms and/or tags could span multiple words.

A safer bet might be to *normalize* your table, and give each tag a separate record in the table, something like this:

```
ID                               | Tags
-----------------------------------------------
b6e490a44fcd5cc92f3d0f97a23f1c83 | foo
b6e490a44fcd5cc92f3d0f97a23f1c83 | bar
b6e490a44fcd5cc92f3d0f97a23f1c83 | bla
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e | ble
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e | blu
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e | bla
```

Now if, for example, you wanted to find out which IDs have the `foo` or `bar` tags you could use the following simple query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID
FROM yourTable
WHERE Tags IN ('foo', 'bar')
```

Note that now the `ID` column is no longer unique and therefore cannot serve as the primary key.  Instead, try adding a new column as the primary key column:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable (
    p_key integer PRIMARY KEY, 
    id TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
    tags TEXT
)
```

Comment: That makes sense, however, how do I avoid returning an ID multiple times when searching for multiple strings. Let's say I search for 'foo bar', I need the ID to be returned just once.

Comment: @MikeSkril Check my query again.  I used `SELECT DISTINCT` which would only return an `ID` once, even if it occurred multiple times.  We could phrase this query multiple ways to remove duplicates, but this might be the simplest way.

Comment: I'm getting an error: `UNIQUE constraint failed` I guess that's because my ID is the primary key and it must be unique, right?
 `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable (id TEXT PRIMARY KEY, tags TEXT)`

Comment: I updated my answer with a `CREATE TABLE` statement which should work.